Unable to read vault properties
I have configured my spring application to use vault with authentication based on approle. I have disabled bootstrapping. Handling approle based authentication programmatically.
Following are the artifacts :
enter image description here
pom.xml :
               
                 <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.2</spring-cloud.version>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

bootstrap.properties :

spring.application.name=mnp
spring.cloud.vault.authentication=approle
spring.cloud.vault.uri=http://127.0.0.1:8200
spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled=true
spring.cloud.vault.kv.backend=secret

package com.hello.vaultDemo;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.SecretBackendConfigurer;
import org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.vault.authentication.AppRoleAuthentication;
import org.springframework.vault.authentication.AppRoleAuthenticationOptions;
import org.springframework.vault.authentication.ClientAuthentication;
import org.springframework.vault.client.VaultEndpoint;
import org.springframework.vault.config.AbstractVaultConfiguration;


@Configuration("CustomVaultConfiguration")
public class CustomVaultConfiguration extends AbstractVaultConfiguration implements  VaultConfigurer{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CustomVaultConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    public VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint() {
        return VaultEndpoint.from("http://127.0.0.1:8200");
    }

    @Override
    public ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication() {
        try {
            String roleId = "d8de84ad-k201-48eb-5e8c-3d502b3e7496";
            String secretId = "e5d8f8a3-8adc-312b-3a09-e494b09e1995";
            AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.AppRoleAuthenticationOptionsBuilder builder = AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.builder().roleId(AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.RoleId.provided(roleId)).path("approle");
            if (StringUtils.hasText(secretId)) {
                builder = builder.secretId(AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.SecretId.provided(secretId));
            }
            return new AppRoleAuthentication(builder.build(), this.restOperations());
        }catch (Exception ex){
            logger.info("exception occurred while vault configuration, msg - {}", ex.getMessage(), ex);
            throw new Error("Failed to initialize vault!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addSecretBackends(SecretBackendConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.add("secret/data/mnp");
    }
}

package com.hello.vaultDemo;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate;
import org.springframework.vault.support.VaultResponse;


@Component
public class test {
    @Value("${one:null}")
    String onee;

    @Value("${two:null}")
    String twoo;

    @Autowired
    VaultTemplate vaultTemplate;

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        VaultResponse response = vaultTemplate.read("secret/data/mnp");
        System.out.println("response - "+ response.getData());
        System.out.println("onee - "+ onee);
        System.out.println("twoo - "+ twoo);

        System.out.println("one "+environment.getProperty("one"));
    }
}


OUTPUT :

response - {data={one=1, three=3, two=2}, metadata={created_time=2024-06-18T04:05:58.519111Z, custom_metadata=null, deletion_time=, destroyed=false, version=1}}
onee - null
twoo - null
one null



application is able to access properties through vaulttemplate.read() method. How can i access properties using @Value or environment bean.
